# Quality of an estimation function

Tags: c#, .net, math, machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to find a way to determine the quality of an estimation function.

I have a dictionary that contains int values.

The total "sum" of this dictionary is Dictionary Key * Value.

```
public int RealValue
{
    get
    {
        return Items.Sum(x => x.Key * x.Value);
    }
}
```

The estimated sum of the Dictionary is calculated by using windows and weights.

```
    public int EstimatedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Items.Where(x => x.Key < window1).Sum(x => weight1 * x.Value) +
                (Items.Where(x => x.Key >= window1 &&  x.Key < window2).Sum(x => weight2 * x.Value)) +
                Items.Where(x => x.Key >= window2 && x.Key < window3).Sum(x => weight3 * x.Value);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to assing a rating to this Estimation Function, i.e. to the quality of the choosen windows and weights.

The estimation function is good, if it can successfully determine which of two dictionaries contain the greater value. It does not matter how close the estimation is to the real count. Of course the Estimation Function is supposed to work with any random pair of dictionaries that are candidates for testing.

What would be a good approach to solve the above problem?

Comment: By a random pair of dictionaries, do you mean any arbitrary dictionaries, or ones generated according to a specific random distribution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the end you are looking at the **ranking problem**, as you assign each object a speciffic order as compares to the remaining ones ("which one is bigger?") and do not care about actual value, thus there is a whole research regarding **ranking evaluation** and in general **learning to rank**.  There are plenty of reliable metrics here, from the simpluest ones - testing number of correct pairwise comparisons (how many times your model gives good ordering of two objects as compared to all compared) to more statistical measures like Kendall tank correlation coefficient.